# When creating web pages, what is the recommended approach for Add/Edit?

Tags: asp.net

Lets say you are developing an web app that requires that you are able to Add/Edit items. The item form contains several input control. Would you separate the add/edit pages or use the page for add/edit and control via querystring (i.e. ItemAddEdit.aspx?isEdit=1)

The advantage I see in separating is that it is easier for the (non-technical) user to type the page and to determine whether it is add or edit. Also, when there would be specific changes to each page (if ever), it would be easier to change.

For the single page, well, you reuse code which eliminates some duplicate code and avoid possible problems.

And no, I can't use routing.

Comment: I will suggest you to use one page and use glyphicons for showing edit and delete icons.

Comment: You can use basic asp.net control like <asp:FormView> <asp:MultiView>. I hope it will meet your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally something which could be a subjective thing, because there's as many ways of doing things as there are coders, and a lot of it can be depending on how your system is set up generally.

But, if I were to recommend, I'd say the way you should do it if working with asp.net web-forms is to make two web pages (add/ edit) and then you use a user-control on those to group up the shared logic between the two pages. After all - that's why we have user controls.
In this way you can have both of your situations, by keeping logic in one file/class, but still have two entry points.
This would also mirror more how MVC does it, which could be considered a plus.

That being said - if your administration functionality is behind login etc, there's nothing to hinder for actually doing it in one and separate with the query string approach, and then just load the data if editing or display "empty"/base data when creating.
You shouldn't have the user type the addresses anyway, but click through the links to follow your flow, so the query string should be a minimal issue.

But for the sake of keeping your functionality clean and divided, I'd personally recommend going for two page / usercontrol approach.